# does it take long to install "npm install --global --production windows-build-tools"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, ngx-admin

I'm trying to fix gyp errors for ngx-admin by

```
'''npm install --global --production windows-build-tools'''
```

but it seems to be taking too long.

Comment: If it's still running in a year it's probably bugged

Comment: it's been for 20 minutes